# Probability Bounds for Intersections

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $P(A) = 0.4$ and $P(B) = 0.7$. Show that $P(A\cap B)$ is such that $0.1 <P(A\cap B) < 0.4$. However, we have to do this without making any more assumptions about $A$ or $B$. I'm not sure how to bound the probability without assuming anything new.

Comment: Hint:  draw some Venn diagrams.  Note that the two equalities are both possible (so your claim is false as stated).

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$1\ge P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.

$P(A\cap B)\le P(A)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$A\cap B\subset A$$

and 
$$1\geq p(A\cup B)=p(A)+p(B)-p(A\cap B)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: The measure of the *intersection* of two events cannot be greater than the measure of the smallest event.

> $$\mathsf P(A\cap B) \;\leq\; \min\{\mathsf P(A), \mathsf P(B)\}$$

Hint 2: The measure of their *union* cannot be greater than one.

> $$\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)\;\leq\; 1$$

Use this to frame boundaries on the size of the intersection.